# Pandas pivot_table with multi-index and duplicate character values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I'm trying to pivot a dataframe like

```
id1 id2 property value
1   2   p        v1  
1   2   p        v2
```

to form

```
id1 id2 p
1   2   v1 & v2
```

My code so far is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=
    {'id1': [1, 1],
     'id2': [2, 2],
     'property': ['p', 'p'],
     'value': ['v1', 'v2']})
df = df.groupby(["id1", "id2", "property"], as_index=False).agg({'value': ' & '.join})  # 1
print(df)
df = df.pivot_table(index=["id1", "id2"], columns="property", values="value")           # 2
print(df)
```

and output is

```
   id1  id2  property  value
0    1    2  p         v1 & v2

pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I can't understand the error message. What is there to aggregate? Should the df be in pivotable form after #1?

Answer (score 3):

Because default aggregate function, `aggfunc` in [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) is mean, error is rased. Change function to `join` for correct output:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=["id1", "id2"], 
                    columns="property", 
                    values="value",
                    aggfunc=' & '.join)  
print (df)
property        p
id1 id2          
1   2     v1 & v2
```

Last for `Multiindex` to columns add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns names and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=["id1", "id2"], 
                    columns="property", 
                    values="value",
                    aggfunc=' & '.join).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id1  id2        p
0    1    2  v1 & v2
```

Comment: Thanks! But as there is only one row in dataframe what does it try to aggregate?

Comment: @tok - because `pivot_table` always aggregate, `pivot` function not.

Comment: Can you please explain? What does rename_axis and reset_index do in this case?

Comment: @tok - sure, `rename_axis` remove `property` - it is column meta information and then `reset_index` convert MultiIndex with levels `id1` and `id2` to columns